# How to clear the Items in sharepoint itempicker

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to clear the sharepoint:itempicker value when clear button is clicked.

please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us what u have tried

Comment: i used this to clear the value
((PickerEntity)IPCustomerPicker.ResolvedEntities[0]).DisplayText="";

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr A.Goutam i found the fix
  ItemPicker picker = IPCustomerPicker;
  picker.Entities.Clear();
  picker.ResolvedEntities.Clear();